# Beste practices with SetRetainInstanceState?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-fragments

I'm currently having issues with fragment lifecycle management. 
Should the activity the fragment is hosted in be recreated I have set SetRetainInstanceState(true) to keep the fragment instance alive.

However, this had lead to some strange behaviour regarding my views. Sometimes I get memory leak warnings concerning a few fragment views and nullpointer exceptions to the activity context.

Wanting to make sure the fragment instance is retained properly: what are best practices regarding the retaining of a fragment (what to keep, what to destroy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetRetainInstanceState(true) makes sure Android retains the fragment while the activity is being recreated. Therefore the activity the fragment was first attached to is not longer there after activity recreation and the fragment is attached to a new activity instance.

To make sure this goes well keep the following things in mind:

Do not keep a reference to the attached activity in your fragment unless absolutely necessary. Use the `getActivity()` method instead which will always return the currently attached fragment (or null if nothing is attached).

If you absolutely have to have a "permanent reference" to the currently attached activity (in which you might want to rethink your design) make sure to update this reference in the onAttach and onDetach methods.

Make sure you retain no object that was initialized using the activity as a context (usually views, adapters and such). To do this, override the Fragments `onDestroyView()`  method that gets called just before activity recreation. Here you can dispose of the views and adapters the fragment still has a active reference to  (usually just setting their reference to null should be enough). You can then recreate the fragment's views and adapters using the new context in the `onCreateView` call.

Comment: Thanks! One more question though, is it ok if I keep a reference to information regarding the views (like a integer or float used to determine the scroll position of a listview)?

Comment: Any object that isn't referencing a context or activity outside of the application context can be safely retained. This includes integers or objects representing a state of the view.